# Is this func possible to cause goroutine leak

Tags: go, memory-leaks, goroutine

```
func startTimer(ctx context.Context, intervalTime int) {
    intervalChan := make(chan bool) 
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            case <-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(intervalTime)):
                intervalChan <- true
            }
        }
    }()


    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case <-intervalChan:
            doSomething()
    }
}
```

Hi,I write a func as above and want to know is it possible to cause goroutine leak.

For example, the first select statement sends a true to intervalChan, then the second select statement receives Done flag from ctx.Done() and return. Will the goroutine be block forever?

Comment: do you cancel your context with defer..  3 paragraph in the documentation
https://golang.org/pkg/context/.. also why use `intervalChan` its much cleaner to implement a context with timeout since you're already using a context and drop `intervalChan`

https://golang.org/pkg/context/#example_WithTimeout

Comment: hi @reticentroot,  in my origin program, context is used for cancelling the timer manually. And using the timeout of context may not be functionally the same with my func

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate this behaviour every time but could be some leak. If `doSomething` do some heavy computation, meanwhile goroutine is blocked on `intervalChan <- true` since it cannot push into the channel. After `doSomething` finish execution and context was cancelled, startTimer exists before goroutine and this will lead into blocked goroutine, because there isn't any consumer of `intervalChan`.

`go version go1.8.3 darwin/amd64`

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func startTimer(ctx context.Context, intervalTime int) {
    intervalChan := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("Done from inside of goroutine.")
                return
            case <-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(intervalTime)):
                fmt.Println("Interval reached.")
                intervalChan <- true
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Done from startTimer.")
            return
        case <-intervalChan:
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("Done")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    startTimer(ctx, 2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my program doSomething() is very light, so it hardly cause a leak. Obviously it is a potential problem, do you have any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The only place your first goroutine could be blocked indefinitely is in `intervalChan <- true`. Put it in another select block to be able to cancel that send:

```
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case <-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(intervalTime)):
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            case intervalChan <- true:
            }
        }
    }
}()
```